# Creating Bash Array with Multiple Elements

Tags: arrays, bash

Very simple bash problem. I have an array that look like:

```
my_array=(1 2 3)
```

However, when I print the array or loop through it, bash only refers to the first element.

```
echo $my_array
1

for element in my_array ; do
    echo $element
done
1
```

How can I access all the elements?

Comment: If you add a Bash shebang, [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problems with the code snippets.  See (the first paragraph of) the [Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for more about ShellCheck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the proper syntax. To display all the elements, use

```
for element in "${my_array[@]}" ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$element"
done
```

`$my_array` is the same as `${my_array[0]}`.

Also, the loop in the original question outputs `my_array`, not `1`. Without a `$`, it's not a variable, it's just a word.